# My outlook 2010 ribbon does not have the vote buttons how do I get the vote commands to show

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010

I have been asked to respond to an email by voting. My outlook 2010 ribbon does not have the vote buttons how do I get the vote commands to show on the ribbon so I can respond?

Answer (score 3):

I had this problem. I fixed it by double clicking the message, and it opened in a window with the vote button. It turns out I had been reading all my messages in the reading pane (View > Reading Pane) without even knowing it. The reading pane has almost everything the message window does but it doesn't have the vote buttons.

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 options:

- When on the overview page in outlook, you can see a preview of the mail and you can click the text "click here to vote" and a popup will appear allowing you to vote.

  [image: option 1]
- The other option is to open the mail, and in the second group (Respond), you will see the "Vote" dropdown in which you can chose the option.

  [image: option 2]

Comment: I appreciate the quick response, thatnk you. But there is no vote option/button/dropdown in the respond group. Just reply, Reply all, forward, meeting and more(forward as attachment). Any other options?

Comment: @Alphonse: have you checked option 1? Do you see that text in the overview page in the outlook client (that check is to see whether they actually send you a vote email)?

Comment: the only thing I see in the email is "Kindly indicate your food preference (VEG /NON-VEG) from the top-left corner of this e-mail asap for my arrangement." There are no vote buttons in the email itself. Could I have an inferior Outlook 2010?

Comment: @Alphonse Are you connecting to Microsoft Exchange using MAPI or Outlook Anywhere? Or using POP/IMAP?

Comment: There seems to be an issue with Sharepoint too if that's been used to send the mail.

Comment: Good question. i am just using IE and stackexchange via company lan

Comment: @Alphonse - That doesn't explain how your getting your email.  If you are not using Exchange the voting options are unlikely to happen.  There is also the real possability that the sender screwed up, and there actually are no options, to anyone who recieved the email.  Honestly you can simply just reply with your option all that happens anyways.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you have set your mail compose options to HTML. Go to *File - Options - Mail - Compose* and change this to *Rich text as default*. Ask the person to resend the email with the voting options. The vote commands should now show up in your Respond menu.